# mootools sexyalert jquery conflict in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, mootools, addeventlistener

Autocomplete for below query works in Firefox 43.0 when I run below code as it is.

If I remove comment symbols from line 7-10 to enable 'sexyalertbox.packed.js' it gives 'ReferenceError: Sexy is not defined'.

If I remove comment symbols from line 7-10 and 13, then commented out the lines 4-6 and 12 now SexyAlertBox works but the autocomplete function as you know.

```
1. <html>
2. <head>
3. <title>Product Categorization</title>
4. <script type="text/javascript" src="res/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
5. <script type="text/javascript" src='res/js/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
6. <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="res/css/jquery-ui.css"></link>

7. <!--<link href="res/css/sexyalertbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
8. <script type="text/javascript" src="res/js/mootools.js"></script>
9. <script type="text/javascript" src="res/js/sexyalertbox.packed.js"></script>
10. <script type="text/javascript" src="res/js/sexyalertbox.v1.1.js"></script>!-->

11. <script>
12. $(function() { $( "#newcat" ).autocomplete({ source: "ac.php?n=catsugg", minLength:2 });  });
13. //window.addEvent('domready', function() { Sexy = new SexyAlertBox(); });
14. </script>
15. </head>
16. <body>
17. <table border='1'>
18. <tr><th>Product Category</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Image URL</th><th>New Category</th></tr>
19. <tr><td id='productcategory'></td><td id='productname'></td><td id='imageurl'></td><td><input type='text' width='100px' id='newcat' onclick="Sexy.info('Y')"></td></tr>
20. </table>
21. </body></html>
```

I tried jQuery.noConflict() as below but it gives $ is not defined error.

How could I make it work or how to convert window.addEvent to jQuery so both of them would work or should I edit sexyalertbox.packed.js?

**As Solution by Sergio**:

Below is the fixed code:

```
1. <html>
2. <head>
3. <title>Product Categorization</title>
4. <script type="text/javascript" src="res/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
5. <script type="text/javascript" src='res/js/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
6. <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="res/css/jquery-ui.css"></link>

7. <link href="res/css/sexyalertbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
8. <script type="text/javascript" src="res/js/mootools.js"></script>
9. <script type="text/javascript" src="res/js/sexyalertbox.packed.js"></script>
10. <script type="text/javascript" src="res/js/sexyalertbox.v1.1.js"></script>

11. <script>
12. window.addEvent('domready', function() { Sexy = new SexyAlertBox(); });
13. jQuery.noConflict(); jQuery(function() { jQuery( "#newcat" ).autocomplete({ source: "ac.php?n=catsugg", minLength:2 });  });
14. </script>
15. </head>
16. <body>
17. <table border='1'>
18. <tr><th>Product Category</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Image URL</th><th>New Category</th></tr>
19. <tr><td id='productcategory'></td><td id='productname'></td><td id='imageurl'></td><td><input type='text' width='100px' id='newcat' onclick="Sexy.info('Y')"></td></tr>
20. </table>
21. </body></html>
```

Comment: Mixing libraries is a pain at the best of times. There surely must be a jQuery plugin which does what you require?

Comment: Yes. There must be a plugin that meets my requirement and I am searching for that. If it is not then developing our own is our next choice.

Comment: You need to run `jQuery.noConflict()` between the load of jQuery and MooTools since that plugin uses `$`. Or you can ammend the plugin to use `document.id` and send a fix to the author.

Comment: Phew. Whew. It was perfect. I know we should add jQuery.noConflict. But where and how was the question. +1 for 'since that plugin uses $' since it is the tip for that

Comment: @Sergio I will mark your solution as answer if you make it as answer.